# Is a separate query good enough, or is there some sort of join I can do?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a small 'invoicing' type system where I have a MySQL table set up for the individual invoices, the invoice lines, and items associated with each invoice, sort of like this:

table invoices:

```
fields: invoice_id | type | fees | comments | company
```

--

table invoice_lines:

```
fields: id | invoice_id | name | description | quantity
```

--

table invoice_affected_items

```
fields: id | invoice_id | item_id
```

I can have many invoice lines and many affected items to one invoice id. In this case would a join be best or should I just join the invoice lines to the table and retrieve the affected items using a separate query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join, but that would result in pulling a lot of extra data. If you join the lines on to the invoices for example, you'd be pulling the invoice multiple times - once for each line...

So to answer your question. I'd do it in separate queries.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO If affected items have a one-to-one relationship with invoice lines (via invoice_lines.id = invoice_affected_items.item_id) you could do one of two things

Either keep you current design and do separate queries

or redesign as follows

- Drop the `invoice_affected_items` tables completely
- Add an `invoice_affected_items` flag to the `invoice_lines` table
- Index `invoice_lines` by (invoice_affected_items,invoice_id) to know what invoices have affected items
- Index `invoice_lines` by (invoice_affected_items,id) to know what invoice lines are the affected items

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relationship between invoice_lines and invoice_affected_items, I would do 2 separate queries.